# Laravel 5.5 - Parse result of db query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am using `Laravel Framework 5.5.26` and I am querying my db with the following call:

```
    $symbolsArray = DB::table('exchanges')
        ->join('markets', 'exchanges.id', '=', 'markets.exchanges_id')
        ->where('name', $exchangeName)
        ->get(array(
            'symbol',
        ));
```

If I `var_dump($symbolsArray)` I get the following output:

```
class Illuminate\Support\Collection#619 (1) {
  protected $items =>
  array(99) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#626 (1) {
      public $symbol =>
      string(7) "BCN/BTC"
    }
    [1] =>
    class stdClass#621 (1) {
      public $symbol =>
      string(8) "BELA/BTC"
    }
    [2] =>
    class stdClass#623 (1) {
      public $symbol =>
      string(7) "BLK/BTC"
    }
    [3] =>
    class stdClass#627 (1) {
      public $symbol =>
      string(8) "BTCD/BTC"
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the `$symbol` like the following:

`$symbolsArray[$key]['symbol']`

However, I get the following error:

```
  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Any suggestions how to access the `symbol` from the query output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a collection of objects, not arrays. So you need to use this syntax to get property of an object in a collection:

```
$symbolsArray[$key]->symbol
```

If you need to get just symbols, use `pluck()` instead of `get()`:

```
->pluck('symbol')->toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple convert given output as an array like shown below**

```
$symbolsArray = DB::table('exchanges')
        ->join('markets', 'exchanges.id', '=', 'markets.exchanges_id')
        ->where('name', $exchangeName)
        ->get(array(
            'symbol',
        ))->toArray(); // get data as array not object
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of DB::table()->get() is always a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections), whose attributes you access like variables within a PHP class with `->`.

In your example, your `$symbolsArray` is not actually an array, you access the content with `$symbolsArray[$key]->symbol`.

Assuming that you are new to Laravel, I suggest you have a look at Laravel's built in ORM [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent). It makes working with Databases easy and straightforward, and if you dive a bit into Eloquent's Collections you will see that they make working with data a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

$symbolsArray is a collection and not an array. The get an array, you could pluck symbol from the collection `$symbolsArray = DB::table('exchanges')
        ->join('markets', 'exchanges.id', '=', 'markets.exchanges_id')
        ->where('name', $exchangeName)
        ->pluck('symbol')->all();` or you could actually convert your collection to an array by `$new_array = $symbolsArray->toArray()`